# Using a Facebook Page as a social plugin to get friend requests from website visitors

Tags: facebook, friends

Can I use my personal Facebook Page as a social plugin on my website, in order to get friend requests from visitors of that website?

I want to generate friend requests through the website, is there a way to use a Like button from a Page to do so?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not a way to do that and I would imagine it violates [Facebook policy](http://www.facebook.com/page_guidelines.php)